# What is a mass moment?

Tags: mass, definition, moment-of-inertia, moment

I am currently reading through a document [Finding Moments of Inertia](https://ocw.mit.edu/courses/mechanical-engineering/2-003j-dynamics-and-control-i-spring-2007/lecture-notes/lec11.pdf) from MIT, page 4, and I am a little confused as to one of the concepts that they use.

In this document, there is mention of a [mass moment](https://www.google.com/search?as_epq=mass+moment). Could someone possibly define this for me please? I can't find anything too clear on the Internet.

Is this synonymous with the first moment of mass?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To TNTCookie and anyone else who may be looking at this post in need of help

I have found the answer. It lies within the definition of a centre of mass:

$$x_{cm} = \frac{\Sigma_{i=1}^{i=N}m_i x_i}{M},$$

where $M$ is the sum of all masses in a system, and the sum in the numerator is the first moment of mass (mass moment).

If we multiply both sides of our equation by $M$, we get:

$$M\times x_{cm} = \Sigma_{i=1}^{i=N}m_i x_i.$$

This works in accordance with the steps in the MIT document as attached. We are summing individual masses multiplied by individual distances from the centre of mass. In the problem in the document, we have to deal with a lack of mass (which can be considered negative mass), and thus we get:

$$M\times |\vec{OC}| = \big(m_{\mbox{cylinder}} \times 0\big) - \big(m_{\mbox{missing cylinder}} \times \frac{R}{2}\big).$$

*Note that the distance from the centre of mass, to the centre of mass of a normal cylinder must be $0$, and the fraction $\frac{R}{2}$ comes from the problem in the attached MIT document.

Answer (score 0):

This is referring to the moment of inertia.

It is similar to how inertia refers to mass, as described in Newton's 1st law, so the tendency of a body to resist acceleration by a force. This is seen as $F=ma$

Now for rotational movements, the physics terms change. The acceleration refers to angular acceleration ($\alpha$), the force to torque ($\tau$), and finally the mass to the moment of inertia ($I$). The equivalent equation is $\tau=I\alpha$.

So in English: the moment of inertia is the tendency of a body to resist angular acceleration, by a torque.

Note: mass moment is not the accepted term. It should be called the moment of inertia and the calculations use it as such.

Comment: Does this not mean that, when they are calculating the 'mass moments', they should square the two distances that they mention (OC and R/2)? As the formula for Moment of Inertia is the a mass multiplied by the radius of gyration squared?

Comment: @Aidanaidan12 This is followed at a later step. I believe they split this calculation for a better flowing structure, where the moment of inertia is finalized in context. It looks like mass moment is a name that the TA has given to this partial calculation step representing mass and its area. Furthermore, there is some inconsistent notation with extra and missing $R$s which shows that there is an issue with these steps.

Comment: Hi TNTCookie, I can't seem to find where the could have completed this calculation. It seems that they use the obtained value of x-coordinate of the COM, $\frac{R}{6}$, straight away after, without any following up on calculation. Its quite odd, I made a post related to this topic on the maths stack exchange a while back and got exactly the same calculation as the document, using mass moments as an explanation. Many thanks, Aidanaidan12

Comment: The reason mass moment of inertia is an accepted term is that there also exists an area moment of inertia which is related to the deflection/bending of an object

Answer (score 0):

Mass moment is slightly different from moment of inertia. It is moment of inertia x total Mass