# What is mass moment?

Tags: reference-frames, mass, definition, moment-of-inertia, moment

My teacher gave the following definition while teaching chapter "Center of mass":
"It is defined as the product of mass of the particle and distance of particle from point about which mass moment is taken"

I could not understand this, so I searched the internet and found a common definition:
" the moment of inertia is the tendency of a body to resist angular acceleration, by a torque."

I am really confused now.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is a mass moment?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/491915/)

Comment: Yeah, but I don't get my teacher's definiton and also are both definitons similar??