# Deduction of mass moments up to the fourth order

Tags: classical-mechanics, mass, tensor-calculus, moment-of-inertia

Could anyone show me the details on the deduction of a discrete object's zeroth, first, second, third and fourth [mass moment](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Moment_(mathematics))? For example, for the hydrogen fluoride with [symmetry](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Molecular_symmetry#Common_point_groups) $C_{\infty V}$? I looked in [Goldstein's book](https://doi.org/10.1119/1.1484149) and another [Physics StackExchange post](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/491915/), but I didn't find anything on it. I would love to see how the idea of moments applied to a discrete distribution of mass produces the results of the first paragraph of this [Wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Moment_(mathematics)):

- zeroth -> rank-0 tensor total mass;
- first -> rank-1 tensor centre of mass;
- second -> the well-known rank-2 tensor  moment of inertia;

I want to deduce the high-order tensor mass moment, and I need to understand how the mass moments produce the low order, but I don't understand this topic.

Comment: You might have more luck if you looked at the multipole expansion in the context of electrostatics; the math is essentially the same but the concept gets more use in that field.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Could anyone show me the details on the deduction of a discrete object's zeroth, first, second, third and fourth [mass moment](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multipole_expansion#Spherical_form)?

To motivate the moment definitions I provide below, suppose that you have a mass density $\rho(\vec x)$ and suppose that you want to compute the convolution of an arbitrary function $f(\vec x)$ with respect to the mass density:
$$
\bar f \equiv \int d^3x f(\vec x)\rho(\vec x)\;.
$$

If you expand the function $f(\vec x)$ about $\vec x=0$ you arrive at an expression (n.b., repeated indices are summed):
$$
\int d^3x f(0)\rho(\vec x)
+\int d^3x \left.\frac{\partial f}{\partial x^i}\right|_{0}x^i\rho(\vec x)
+\int d^3x \frac{1}{2!}\left.\frac{\partial^2 f}{\partial x^i x^j}\right|_{0}x^i x^j\rho(\vec x)
+\int d^3x \frac{1}{3!}\left.\frac{\partial^3 f}{\partial x^i x^j x^k}\right|_{0}x^i x^j x^k\rho(\vec x)
+\int d^3x \frac{1}{4!}\left.\frac{\partial^4 f}{\partial x^i x^j x^k x^\ell}\right|_{0}x^i x^j x^k x^\ell\rho(\vec x)
+\ldots
$$
$$
=f(0)M_0 
+ \left.\frac{\partial f}{\partial x^i}\right|_{0}M^i_1
+ \frac{1}{2!}\left.\frac{\partial^2 f}{\partial x^i x^j}\right|_{0} M^{ij}_2
+ \frac{1}{3!}\left.\frac{\partial^3 f}{\partial x^i x^j x^k}\right|_{0}M^{ijk}_3
+ \frac{1}{4!}\left.\frac{\partial^4 f}{\partial x^i x^j x^k x^\ell}\right|_{0}M^{ijk\ell}_4
+\ldots\;,
$$
where
$$
M_0 \equiv \int d^3x \rho(\vec x)\;, \tag{0}
$$
$$
M^i_1 \equiv \int d^3x x^i \rho(\vec x)\;, \tag{1}
$$
$$
M^{ij}_2 \equiv \int d^3x x^i x^j \rho(\vec x)\;, \tag{2}
$$
$$
M^{ijk}_3 \equiv \int d^3x x^i x^j x^k\rho(\vec x)\;, \tag{3}
$$
$$
M^{ijk\ell}_4 \equiv \int d^3x x^i x^j x^k x^\ell\rho(\vec x)\;, \tag{4}
$$
$$
\ldots
$$
$$
M^{i_1i_2\ldots i_n}_n\equiv \int d^3x x^{i_1} x^{i_2}\ldots x^{i_n} \rho(\vec x)\;, \tag{n}
$$

We can refer to $M_n$ above as the "n-th" moment.

---

The n-th moment transforms like a rank-n tensor. To see this, consider the density in a different coordinate frame $\tilde x^i = R^{ij}x_j$. In this frame we have a different density function $\tilde \rho (\tilde x)$, but it is related to the initial frame's density function like:
$$
\tilde \rho(\tilde{\vec x}) = \rho(R^{-1}{\tilde{\vec x}})\;.
$$
So, for example:
$$
\tilde{M^{ij}_2} \equiv \int d^3\tilde x \tilde x^{i}\tilde x^{j}\tilde \rho(\tilde x) = \int d^3x \det(R^{-1}) R^{ik}x^k R^{j\ell}x^{\ell}\rho(\vec x)
$$
$$
= R^{ik}R^{j\ell}M^{k\ell}_2\;.
$$

This transformation property is appealing and is one reason why we like to use these moments.

However, these transformation properties alone do not *uniquely* define the moments proposed above. For example, instead of considering $M_2^{ij}$ we could consider a different moment like
$$
N_2^{ij}\equiv M_2^{ij} - \alpha\delta^{ij}\int d^3x |\vec x|^2\rho(\vec x)\;,
$$
where $\alpha$ is an arbitrary number. For example, if we wanted to make $N_2$ a traceless rank-2 tensor we could set $\alpha = \frac{1}{3}$.

---

The upshot is that, although the set of $n$ equations for the $M_n$ above provides a useful definition for moments, it is not the only definition one could choose. One's choice is typically dictated by the problem one is trying to solve. For example, another systematic way to define moments is [the multipole expansion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multipole_expansion#Spherical_form) in terms of spherical harmonics, which tends to be most useful when considering problems that involve an inverse power-law potential like a gravitation potential or an electrostatic potential.

Comment: Many thanks, @hft!